# Phrase meaning "perceptible on the timescale of human attention"

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there a word/phrase meaning "perceptible on the timescale of human attention"?

For example, a light turning on and off once per second qualifies. A laser turning on and off at 100Hz is too fast. The movement of the sun and moon in the sky is perceptible, although barely so... you'd have to make a record of where they were (e.g. sundial) and note changes over the span of minutes. Movement of glaciers (in general) is too slow to be perceptible in this way.

Quantitatively I would put this at 10Hz - 0.01Hz, but I'm wondering if a more evocative phrase exists, since I'm looking at the qualitative/evocative aspects of it, rather than quantitative.

For example:

> The sway of the trees and the movement of a clock pendulum are _____; the beating of a bee's wings and the movement of a glacier are not.

Comment: 'Humanly perceivable'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Perceptible" is the word you're looking for, which you actually used in your question. Is there a different sense you're trying to bring out that I've missed?

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perceptible

capable of being perceived especially by the senses
 ·a perceptible change in her tone
 ·a barely perceptible light

Comment: I think the nuance is a definite "by humans" qualifier, where, normally, that is merely implied and only qualified when referring to members of different species or equipment.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Chris Bergin's answer, I'd also suggest:

- perceivable
- discernible
- distinguishable

It's an interesting question--I'm not aware, off-hand, of any words that roll the "by humans" into the core word, possibly because it's implied unless qualified with "by member_of_a_different_species" or a piece of equipment.

That said, I'd hold off on formally accepting an answer because there might be a fancy, technical term for this.  *(Failing that, we could certainly coin one by combining "anthro-" with one of Ancient Greek words for perception.)*